# How could I find where this 'Segmentation fault (core dumped)' error occurs?

Tags: c++, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I hope y'all having a nice day ^^.

I'm doing some Binary Search Tree homework and it's been a nightmare. I made a Binary Node Class, a Binary Tree Class (parent), a Binary Search Tree Class (son) and a Main program to test it. The thing is that when I execute the main program, I get a 'Segmentation Fault (core dumped)' error in the method I use to print the tree.

**Header file of bnode_c:**

```
#ifndef __BNODE_C__
#define __BNODE_C__

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

template <typename TDato = int>
class bnode_c
{   private:
        TDato data_;

    public:
        bnode_c<TDato>* left_;

        bnode_c<TDato>* right_;

        bnode_c(void);

        TDato& get_data(void);
};

#endif
```

**CPP file of bnode_c:**

```
#include "../include/bnode_c.hpp"

using namespace std;

template <typename TDato>
bnode_c<TDato>::bnode_c(void):
    left_(NULL),
    right_(NULL),
    data_(NULL) {}

template <typename TDato>
bnode_c<TDato>::bnode_c(const TDato& dat):
    left_(NULL),
    right_(NULL),
    data_(dat) {}


template <typename TDato>
bnode_c<TDato>::~bnode_c(void)
{   left_ = NULL;

    right_ = NULL;
}


template <typename TDato>
TDato& bnode_c<TDato>::get_data(void) { return data_;}
```

**Header file of btree_c:**

```
#ifndef __BTREE_C__
#define __BTREE_C__

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cassert>

#include "../src/queue_c.cpp"
#include "../src/pair_c.cpp"

using namespace std;

template <typename Clave = int>
class btree_c
{   
    protected:
        int depth_;

        unsigned int size_;

        bnode_c<Clave>* root_;

    public:
        btree_c(void);

        btree_c(bnode_c<Clave>*);

        ~btree_c(void);

        void cut(bnode_c<Clave>*);

        bool is_empty(void) const;

        ostream& lvl_print(ostream&, bnode_c<Clave>*) const;

        void insert(const Clave);

        bnode_c<Clave>* get_root(void) const;

    private:
        void insert_branch(const Clave, bnode_c<Clave>*&);

        bnode_c<Clave>* search_branch(Clave, bnode_c<Clave>*) const;
};

#endif
```

**CPP file of btree_c:**

```
#include "../include/btree_c.hpp"

using namespace std;

template <typename Clave>
btree_c<Clave>::btree_c(void):
depth_(-1),
size_(0),
root_(NULL) {}


template <typename Clave>
btree_c<Clave>::btree_c(bnode_c<Clave>* root):
depth_(0),
size_(1),
root_(root) {}


template <typename Clave>
btree_c<Clave>::~btree_c(void) { cut(root_); }


template <typename Clave>
void btree_c<Clave>::cut(bnode_c<Clave>* node)
{   if (node == NULL) return;

    cut(node->left_);
    cut(node->right_);

    delete node;
}


template <typename Clave>
bool btree_c<Clave>::is_empty(void) const { return (size_ == 0); }


template <typename Clave>
ostream& btree_c<Clave>::lvl_print(ostream& os, bnode_c<Clave>* root) const
{   queue_c<pair_c<bnode_c<Clave>*, int> > queue;

    bnode_c<Clave>* node;

    int level, current_level = 0;

    pair_c<bnode_c<int>*, int> p(root, current_level);

    queue.add(p);

    while (!queue.is_empty())
    {   pair_c<bnode_c<int>*, int> pair;

        pair = queue.get_front();

        queue.remove();

        if (pair.b > current_level)
        {   current_level = pair.b;

            os << endl << "Level[" << current_level << "]: ";
        }

        if(node != NULL)
        {   os << node->get_data() << " ";

            pair_c<bnode_c<int>*, int> l(node->left_, level + 1);
            pair_c<bnode_c<int>*, int> r(node->right_, level + 1);

            queue.add(l);

            queue.add(r);
        }

        else os << "Empty tree";
    }
}


template <typename Clave>
void btree_c<Clave>::insert(const Clave clave)
{   if (root_ == NULL)
      root_ = new bnode_c<Clave>(clave);
    else 
      insert_branch(clave, root_);

    size_++;
}


template <typename Clave>
bnode_c<Clave>* btree_c<Clave>::get_root(void) const { return root_; }


template <typename Clave>
void btree_c<Clave>::insert_branch(const Clave clave, bnode_c<Clave>*& node)
{   if (node == NULL)
        node = new bnode_c<Clave>(clave);

    else if (clave < node->get_data())
        insert_branch(clave, node->left_);

    else insert_branch(clave, node->right_);
}
```

**Header file of bsearch_tree_s:**

```
#ifndef __BSEARCH_TREE_S__
#define __BSEARCH_TREE_S__

#include "../src/btree_c.cpp"

using namespace std;

template <typename Clave = int>
class bsearch_tree_s: public btree_c<Clave>
{       public:
                bsearch_tree_s(void);

                bsearch_tree_s(bnode_c<Clave>*);

                ~bsearch_tree_s(void);

                ostream& write(ostream&);
};

#endif
```

**CPP file of bsearch_tree_s:**

```
#include "../include/bsearch_tree_s.hpp"

using namespace std;

template <typename Clave>
bsearch_tree_s<Clave>::bsearch_tree_s(void) {}


template <typename Clave>
bsearch_tree_s<Clave>::bsearch_tree_s(bnode_c<Clave>* node):
btree_c<Clave>::btree_c(node) {}


template <typename Clave>
bsearch_tree_s<Clave>::~bsearch_tree_s(void){}


template <typename Clave>
ostream& bsearch_tree_s<Clave>::write(ostream& os)
{ return btree_c<Clave>::lvl_print(os, btree_c<Clave>::get_root()); }
```

**Header file of pair_c:**

```
#ifndef __PAIR_C__
#define __PAIR_C__

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cassert>

#include "../src/bnode_c.cpp"

using namespace std;

template<typename TDato1, typename TDato2>
class pair_c
{   public:
        TDato1 a;

        TDato2 b;

        pair_c(void);

        pair_c(bnode_c<int>*, int);

        void operator= (pair_c<TDato1, TDato2>);
};

#endif
```

**CPP file of pair_c:**

```
#include "../include/pair_c.hpp"

using namespace std;

template <typename TDato1, typename TDato2>
pair_c<TDato1, TDato2>::pair_c(void):
    a(NULL),
    b(0) {}


template <typename TDato1, typename TDato2>
pair_c<TDato1, TDato2>::pair_c(bnode_c<int>* node, int x):
    a(node),
    b(x) {}


template <typename TDato1, typename TDato2>
void pair_c<TDato1, TDato2>::operator= (pair_c<TDato1, TDato2> pair)
{   a = pair.a;

    b = pair.b;
}
```

**Header file of queue_c:**

```
#ifndef __QUEUE_C__
#define __QUEUE_C__

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cassert>

#include "../src/dll_c.cpp"
#include "pair_c.hpp"

using namespace std;

template <typename TDato = pair_c<bnode_c<int>*, int> >
class queue_c
{   private:
        int sz_;

        dll_c<TDato> l_;  

    public:
        queue_c(void);

        ~queue_c(void);

        void add(TDato&);

        TDato& get_front(void) const;

        int get_size(void) const;

        void remove(void);

        bool is_empty(void);

        ostream& write(ostream& os) const;
};

template <typename TDato>
ostream& operator <<(ostream&, const queue_c<TDato>&);

#endif
```

**CPP file of queue_c:**

```
#include "../include/queue_c.hpp"

using namespace std;

template <typename TDato>
queue_c<TDato>::queue_c(void):
    sz_(0),
    l_() {}


template <typename TDato>
queue_c<TDato>::~queue_c(void) {}


template <typename TDato>
void queue_c<TDato>::add(TDato& data)
{   node_c<TDato>* node = new node_c<TDato>(data);

    l_.insert_tail(node);

    sz_++;
}


template <typename TDato>
TDato& queue_c<TDato>::get_front(void) const
{   //assert(!(is_empty()));

    return l_.get_head()->get_data();
}


template <typename TDato>
int queue_c<TDato>::get_size(void) const { return sz_; }


template <typename TDato>
void queue_c<TDato>::remove(void)
{   //assert(!(is_empty()));

    l_.extract_head();

    sz_--;
}


template <typename TDato>
bool queue_c<TDato>::is_empty(void) { l_.is_empty(); }


template <typename TDato>
ostream& queue_c<TDato>::write(ostream& os) const { l_.xtrn_write(os); }


template <typename TDato>
ostream& operator <<(ostream& os, const queue_c<TDato>& q) { return q.write(os); }
```

I've tried using cout to determine which instruction inside btree_c:lvl_print(ostream&, bnode_c*) is causing the error, but I noticed that the program doesn't even start to execute the method.

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Please don't forget the ***minimal*** part of your [mcve]. And please learn how to use a debugger to catch crashes and how tu use it to locate when and where in your code it happens.

Comment: Now is a good time to run your program under a debugger and step through the program function by function, line by line if you must.

Comment: You say that your application has generated a core dump. This should contain the call stack of the problem. Please have a look at this call stack, it should point you right at the problem.

Comment: Templated classes cannot be implemented in a cpp file. You overcome this problem by including the cpp files. This is not a good practice.

Comment: `pair_c` is too general a template. Try to create a `pair_c<std::string, std::string>` and see what the compiler says.

Comment: @Simeón It is very easy to find where a segmentation fault occurred. Just after writing each new function and moreover after adding a new line in an existent function  test your program. That is all.

Comment: `bsearch_tree_s` does not add anything to `btree_c`, neither data nor functionality. `btree_c` already is a binary search tree, so why does `bsearch_tree_s` exist?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm sorry, I didn't want to make the post too long, but the function that causes the error uses 4 different classes and each one of them depends on different methods. I deleted all the methods that were unnecesary.

And, yeah, I have to learn how to use a debugger. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: `bsearch_tree_s<Clave>` exists because my teacher says so. I know it doesn't add anything, but thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 1):

try to use a debugger

run the code with gdb ./yourCode

use run command to start the program

when it's crash use bt(back trace) command  to find where is happened

[some gdb commands that can help you](https://darkdust.net/files/GDB%20Cheat%20Sheet.pdf)